# Understanding simple example in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

im trying to learn group theory to understand particle physics and im currently reading: "A Simple Introduction to Particle Physics ,Part I - Foundations and the Standard Model". In the chapter called Group Actions he uses an example of three colorred eggs (ROY) and defines the actions:

1. Let e be doing nothing to the set, so e(ROY ) = (ROY ).
2. Let g1 be a cyclic permutation of the three, g1(ROY ) = (OY R)
3. Let g2 be a cyclic permutation in the other direction, g2(ROY ) = (Y RO)
4. Let g3 be swapping the first and second, g3(ROY ) = (ORY )
5. Let g4 be swapping the first and third, g4(ROY ) = (Y OR)
6. Let g5 be swapping the second and third, g5(ROY ) = (RY O)

which gives us this table:

$
\begin{array}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline(G, \star) & e & g_{1} & g_{2} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} \\
\hline e & e & g_{1} & g_{2} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} \\
\hline g_{1} & g_{1} & g_{2} & e & g_{5} & g_{3} & g_{4} \\
\hline g_{2} & g_{2} & e & g_{1} & g_{4} & g_{5} & g_{3} \\
\hline g_{3} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{5} & e & g_{1} & g_{2} \\
\hline g_{4} & g_{4} & g_{5} & g_{3} & g_{2} & e & g_{1} \\
\hline g_{5} & g_{5} & g_{3} & g_{4} & g_{1} & g_{2} & e \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

Later in the paper every element of the group is associated with a unit vector $e \rightarrow |e> $ for every element of the group. Then the represantation of the group acting on these vectors is defined as:
$D(g_i)|g_j>=|g_i*g_j>$. If we follow these rules in the end we are going to get a 6x6 Matrix for every element of the group. Now my question is this: How can we determine what the vectors are that these matrices act on? How would i represent the three eggs using vectors? I tried for example using:

$
|e>=
\begin{pmatrix}
R \\
Y \\
O \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$
which would seem the natural choice for me. Now $D(g_i)$ is calculated to be:
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

But acting on the vector with matrix is giving the eggs in the wrong order. I am clearly confusing something so could anybody help me with explaining how all of this works?

Answer (score 1):

The 6x6 matrices you have described are no longer acting on the original eggs. The representation you have described is the *regular representation* where the group is acting on itself: each unit vector in the 6 dimensional space corresponds to an element of the group.

If you want a matrix representation of the group that acts on the eggs, you could use a 3x3 matrix where each row and column corresponds to an egg. Now each unit vector in the 3 dimensional space corresponds to an egg.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but with this represantation can the group elements only act on themselves? Can they not act on 6- dimensional vectors anymore? If they could, can they still rearrange objects?

Comment: While reading your answer again i realized that i dont understand what we exactly mean with objects as well. If you have the time can you check the most recent question i posted to see if you clarify what it is meant by objects there?

Comment: The 6x6 matrices still act on 6 dimensional vectors. The unit 6-dimensional vectors correspond to the elements of the group. When you act by a matrix on a unit vector (which corresponds to an element of the group) in the usual way, you get another unit vector (which corresponds to another element of the group). So considering unit vectors only, each 6x6 matrix acts as a permutation on the elements of the group. An "object" in this context can be literally anything and doesn't have any special meaning or restrictions.

Comment: There are uncountably many unit vectors. I would use the term "standard basis vectors."